# Do I need a transit visa in UK if I don't meet the exemption criteria for my returning trip (yet)?

Tags: transit-visas

> I'm travelling to China from US and will be transiting at LHR. Here's
>   my situation: I booked a round trip (virgin atlantic) from US to China
>   flying on 12/23/2018 and returning 1/4/2019. By 12/23, when I arrive
>   at LHR, my current US working visa will be expired.
>
> I do have a valid Canada visa. The layover is about 4 hours and
>   doesn't need to go through border control. I looked online and it
>   seems I don't need one as long as I have "a visa for Canada, New
>   Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any
>   country)", so this criteria is met due to my Canada visa.
>
> However, at that time, I will not meet the returning exemption
>   criteria (yet) because I won't have a valid US visa that grants me
>   reentry (which I'll renew in China). Will this fact keep me from
>   boarding my flight back to China?

I don't think I have the time for applying a transit visa at the moment, so I'm really hoping this doesn't stop me from going back to China.....
Million thanks!

Comment: The airline will not care that the _return_ visa has not been arranged in allowing you to board the _outward flight_. Incidentally, others on this site have said that because of the rather different way the USA measures visa validity, just-finished visas have been accepted for airside transit. With your Canadian visa, this is irrelevant.